# Cleaning HTML in .txt files with python and converting to csv (should be very easy but I'm a newbie)

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing, data-cleaning

Okay, go easy on me here. I've been coding about for about 48 hours cumulatively (ᵔᴥᵔ)

I have a folder full of identical .txt files (as in, the values vary, but the format is exactly the same). The text in them looks like this:

```html
<html><head></head><body><html><head></head><body>{"Flashpoint Swindon":{"count":3,"capacity":88,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: now (4:49 PM)"},"Oakwood":{"count":45,"capacity":75,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: now (4:49 PM)"},"Big Depot Leeds":{"count":32,"capacity":105,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: now (4:49 PM)"},"Depot Birmingham":{"count":45,"capacity":180,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: now (4:49 PM)"},"Depot Climbing Sheffield":...}}</body></html>
```

There are 43 records in each file. The text files also have HTML tags at the start and end.

My end goal is a csv file with information for all dates that looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
| Date     | Centre             | Count | Capacity  | Time   |
| 20200822 | Flashpoint Swindon | 3     | 88        | 19:07  |
| 20200822 | Oakwood            | 45    | 75        | 18:11  |
| 20200822 | Big Depot Leeds    | 32    | 105       | 20:20  |
+----------+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

The file name provides the date information (e.g. 2020-08-22-17-49-40_capacity.txt). So all of the information is there, I just don't know how to finish getting from A to B.

So far I've written this to clean the text file into something that can be worked with as a csv:

```
import re

my_file = open("2020-08-22-17-49-40_capacity", "r+")
text = my_file.read()
text = re.sub('<html><head></head><body>', '', text)
text = re.sub('</body></html>', '', text)
text = re.sub('},', '\n', text)
text = re.sub('{', '', text)
text = re.sub('}}', '', text)
text = re.sub(':', ',', text)

print(text)

import sys 

stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("cleaned.txt", "w")
```

This seems to be working okay - here's what the text ends up looking like:

```
"Flashpoint Swindon","count",0,"capacity",88,"lastUpdated","Last updated, 1 hour ago (7,07 PM)"
"Oakwood","count",0,"capacity",75,"lastUpdated","Last updated, 2 hours ago (6,11 PM)"
"Big Depot Leeds","count",11,"capacity",105,"lastUpdated","Last updated, 1 min ago (8,20 PM)"
"Depot Birmingham","count",8,"capacity",180,"lastUpdated","Last updated, 1 min ago (8,20 PM)"
"Depot Climbing Sheffield"...
```

The output is a little temperamental - sometimes it works and sometimes it spits out a blank .txt file. I've not figured out why.

I realise I'm asking for a HUGE amount of help here, but if anyone can offer help for even parts of what I'm doing, that would be amazing.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: still not too clear on the format of the files, do you mean its a regular html type file, but in the body it has the info you need?

Comment: You should use an HTML parser (to get rid of the HTML tags) and the read the content you are interested in as JSON (that's what it is obviously). This makes your code maintainable and more robust to markup changes.

Comment: @TochiBedford The files are saved as .txt but they have HTML tags at the start and end. All of the information is between the '<html><head></head><body>' at the beginning and the '</body></html>' at the end. Hope that helps - thank you for taking a look.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thanks so much for taking a look. Yep, you're right that the source of the files is JSON. I'm completely new to this, so I was just trying to use the tools that I already knew how to use a little (i.e. editing strings in text files). I'll look into HTML parsing.

Comment: Continuing with @MauriceMeyer 's idea to get to exact form in which you require... You can use `pandas` library..save json as `.csv` files. Also you can extract `Date` from the filename like this - `''.join("2020-08-22-17-49-40_capacity.txt".split('_')[0].split('-')[:3])` and then put that date in a column of pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, @AbhilashAwasthi - that's really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) to parse the HTML/input file and read the 'body' as json.
Convert the time into a datetime object, so could calculate with it and/or format it properly:

```
import re
import csv
import json
import datetime as dt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

now = dt.date.today()
data = """<html><head></head><body>{"Flashpoint Swindon":{"count":0,"capacity":88,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: 1 hour ago (7:07 PM)"},"Oakwood":{"count":0,"capacity":75,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: 2 hours ago (6:11 PM)"},"Big Depot Leeds":{"count":11,"capacity":105,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: 1 min ago (8:20 PM)"},"Depot Birmingham":{"count":8,"capacity":180,"lastUpdated":"Last updated: 1 min ago (8:20 PM)"}}</body></html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

content = json.loads(soup.body.text)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(["Date", "Centre", "Count", "Capacity", "Time"])  # write headers
    for item in content:
        # parse the time and create a datetime object
        _time = re.search(r"\((.*)\)", content[item]['lastUpdated']).groups()[0]
        _timeObj = dt.datetime.strptime(_time, "%I:%M %p")
        writer.writerow([now, item, content[item]['count'], content[item]['capacity'], _timeObj.strftime('%H:%M')])

print(open('test.csv').read())
```

Output:

```
Date;Centre;Count;Capacity;Time
2020-08-23;Flashpoint Swindon;0;88;19:07
2020-08-23;Oakwood;0;75;18:11
2020-08-23;Big Depot Leeds;11;105;20:20
2020-08-23;Depot Birmingham;8;180;20:20
```

Comment: Oh my word, Maurice! Thank you so so so much. This is amazing. I'd taken your comment on board and had already started a new jupyter notebook using requests and BeautiulSoup, but getting to this point would have taken me days. Am I right in thinking that I can use the glob module to run through all .txt files in the folder?

Comment: Yes, use glob :)

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer works - I would like to suggest this alternative for two reasons:
First, it's not a good idea to parse html with regex - search around, there are a lot of discussions about it; so it's generally better to use an html parser. Second, the actual data is in json format, so it's best to load it into pandas and save as csv.

So disregarding dt formatting etc. I would do something like this:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import json
import pandas as pd

events = """[your html]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(events)
jst= json.loads(doc.xpath('//body/text()')[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(jst)
df
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
               Flashpoint Swindon   Oakwood     Big Depot Leeds     Depot Birmingham
count          0                     0          11                  8
capacity       88                    75          105               180
lastUpdated     Last updated: 1 hour ago (7:07 PM)  Last updated: 2 hours ago (6:11 PM)     Last updated: 1 min ago (8:20 PM)   Last updated: 1 min ago (8:20 PM)
```

You can then save it to csv using:

```
df.transpose().to_csv()
```

Comment: Jack, thanks so much for taking the time to offer an alternative answer. I really really appreciate it. What you're saying makes sense, and I'm certainly going to have a read about it. All of this is a huge learning curve but I'm really enjoying it, and the Stack Overflow community has been incredible.